# Kotlin compiler cannot verify generic type of class

Tags: generics, kotlin

**TL;DR**

The Kotlin compiler gives an error (type mismatch) here:

```
fun <T: A()> getUtil(t: T): Util<T> = if (t is B) UtilB() else // ...
```

With signature of class `B` being: `class B : A()`, class `Util` being `class Util<T: A>` and class `UtilB` being `class UtilB: Util<B>()`.

The Kotlin compiler gives a warning (unchecked cast) here:

```
fun <T: A()> getUtil(t: T): Util<T> = if (t is B) UtilB() as Util<T> else // ...
```

To my understanding Kotlin smart cast should know that `UtilB() as Util<T>` is checked by `t is B`.

Java code and compiler give the exact same result.

As far as I know this must be a limitation on Java generics. How can I fix this?

**Problem description**

I have the following setup where an abstract class has multiple implementations and a util class that provides the same functionality for each of those implementations.

To be type safe I figured I would create an abstract class `Util<T: A>` and for each derived class of `A` another `UtilB: Util<B>` class.

To get the right util class for each implementation, I created a function on a companion object `getUtil` which returns the correct util class for each implementation based on a parameter of generic type T which extends A: `T: A` thus having return type `Util<T>`.

However, when I wrote the function body for each derived class of `A` by checking the type of the parameter with `is B` and then returning the correct util with `UtilB()`, the Kotlin compiler gave me an error at the return point saying that `UtilB` isn't of type `Util<T>` even though it should be.

I then casted `UtilB` to `Util<B>` and that worked but gave me an error "Unchecked cast". According to my understanding Kotlin smart cast should be able to figure out that it is indeed a valid checked cast (checked with `is B`) and after running a quick test it turned out to be valid as well...

I rewrote the same code in Java with the exact same results...

As far as I know this is a limitation of Java/Kotlin generics.
I would like to know how I can check this cast. Is it even possible?

**Code**

Here is a minimal working (or not working) example:

```
abstract class A
class B : A()
class C : A()

abstract class Util<T : A> {
    abstract fun getName(): String
    companion object {
        fun <T : A> getUtil(t: T): Util<T> = when(t) {
            is B -> UtilB() as Util<T> // warning
            is C -> UtilC() // this event gives an error
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("No util for this class.")
        }
    }
}

class UtilB : Util<B>() {
    override fun getName(): String = "B"
}

class UtilC : Util<C>() {
    override fun getName(): String = "C"
}

fun main() {
    val b = B()
    val c = C()
    val utilB = Util.getUtil(b)
    val utilC = Util.getUtil(c)
    println(utilB.getName()) // prints B
    println(utilC.getName()) // prints C
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified version that works:

```kotlin
abstract class A
class B : A()
class C : A()

abstract class Util<T : A> {
    abstract fun getName(): String
    companion object {
        fun <T : A> getUtil(t: T): Util<A> = when(t) {    // here return Util<A>
            is B -> UtilB()                               // No need cast
            is C -> UtilC()
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("No util for this class.")
        }
    }
}

class UtilB : Util<A>() {                   // Replace B by A
    override fun getName(): String = "B"
}

class UtilC : Util<A>() {                  // Replace C by A
    override fun getName(): String = "C"
}

fun main() {
    val b = B()
    val c = C()
    val utilB = Util.getUtil(b)
    val utilC = Util.getUtil(c)
    println(utilB.getName()) // prints B
    println(utilC.getName()) // prints C
}
```

But I'm not sure you're on the right way.
When I see this pattern I see sealed classes.

Here is an implementation using sealed classes:

```kotlin
sealed class AA {
    class BB : AA()
    class CC : AA()
}
sealed class AAU {
    abstract fun getName():String

    class BBU : AAU() {
        override fun getName()= "BB"
    }

    class CCU : AAU(){
        override fun getName()= "CC"
    }
}

fun getU(aa: AA) =
    when(aa) {
        is AA.BB -> AAU.BBU()
        is AA.CC -> AAU.CCU()
    }

fun main() {
   val bb = AA.BB()
   val cc = AA.CC()
   val bbu = getU(bb)
   val ccu = getU(cc)
   println(bbu.getName())
   println(ccu.getName())
}
```

So here no need to throw exception.

It could be even simpler:

```kotlin
sealed class AA {
    class BB : AA()
    class CC : AA()
}

fun getName(aa: AA) =
        when(aa) {
            is AA.BB -> "BB"
            is AA.CC -> "CC"
        }

fun main() {
    val bb = AA.BB()
    val cc = AA.CC()
    println(getName(bb))
    println(getName(cc))
}
```

As I don't know your context the last implementation it's perhaps not the right approach.

Comment: With your first version I loose the type safety of UtilB as it is not a util class solely for B anymore but for A in general. E.g. `val util: Util<B> = UtilB()` would not work anymore.

Comment: I do not know about sealed classes and will take a look into them. Might have a problem with them because my classes A, B and C are actually JPA entities...
As for you last example: correct, this does not work because there are more methods on Util and they differ in implementation quite a lot.
Thanks for your quick response, I will look into sealed classes or any other additional hint you might have :)

Comment: @Wernerson ok I understand more your problem. In your case you do not have type safety because you are manually mapping B or C to UtilB or UtilC. Do you have the ability to modify A, B and C classes?

Comment: Within certain limits yes. Class `A` is an abstract class and `B` and `C` are derivatives of it. All of them are JPA entities.

Answer (score 0):

> To my understanding Kotlin smart cast should know that `UtilB() as Util<T>` is checked by `t is B`.

No it shouldn't because it's wrong. It's perfectly legal to call

```
getUtil<A>(B())
```

in which case `t is B` is true, but `T` is `A` and `UtilB` doesn't extend `Util<A>`. You may try to fix it with covariance, but that won't work either:

```
class D : B()

getUtil<D>(D())
```

Now `UtilB` has to extend `Util<D>` as well.

A possible solution is to add an [F-bounded type parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification) to `A`, but the method still has to be a member to avoid casts (Kotlin doesn't refine type parameters inside a `when` branch like e.g. Scala does):

```
abstract class A<T : A<T>> {
    abstract fun util(): Util<T>
}
class B : A<B>() {
    override fun util() = UtilB()
}
class C : A<C>() {
    override fun util() = UtilC()
}

abstract class Util<T : A<T>> {
    abstract fun getName(): String
}

class UtilB : Util<B>() {
    override fun getName(): String = "B"
}

class UtilC : Util<C>() {
    override fun getName(): String = "C"
}
```

Comment: Yes but `B` extends `A` so the first one should work shouldn't it?

Comment: Your second argument is a valid point but your answer doesn't solve my problem. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: No, `B` extends `A` doesn't imply `Util<B>` extends `Util<A>`. Please read about variance: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance.

Comment: See the edit for a possible fix, if the limitation is acceptable. If it isn't, I believe you have to live with casts (but you should still use `A<T : A<T>>` to make the casts actually correct).